# Keep open braces on the same line in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

By default, my VS 2019 creates new function definitions like this:

```c
void somefunction() 
{
    
}
```

Is there a setting I can change to default it to this?

```c
void somefunction() {
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Tools** → **Options** → **Text Editor** → **C/C++** → **Formatting** → **New Lines** → **Position of open braces for functions** → **Keep on same line ...**

[image: Position of open braces for functions]